# Attachment Parameter missing in Collection runner

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

pls refer my screenshor where the parameter data[file] (excel attachemnt) is available in body but while executing the same using collection runner this parameter is missing due to which my API is getting failed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by creating my attachment sheets under working directory of postman.

https://community.postman.com/t/parameter-missing-in-collection-runner/16462